# How can I eliminate duplicate data in column

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to eliminate duplicates and show one time

for example

```
SELECT 'apple, apple, orange'
FROM dual;
```

I would like to show

```
apple, orange
```

as another example.

```
SELECT 'apple, apple, apple, apple,'
FROM dual;
```

I just want to show

```
apple
```

This code shows

```
with data as
(
  select 'apple, apple, apple, apple' col from dual
)
select listagg(col, ',') within group(order by 1) col
  from (
        select distinct regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, level) col
          from data
        connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',')
       )
```

Comment: Why in title you have date?

Comment: @user7294900 sorry it meant duplicate data

Comment: You can edit your question title

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza. Thanks!!! I did it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will eliminate duplicates:

**[SQL Demo](https://rextester.com/BAD12000)**

```
with temp as
(
    select 1 Name, 'test1' Project, 'apple, apple, orange' Error  from dual
    union all
    select 2, 'test2', 'apple, apple, apple, apple,' from dual
), split as (
    select distinct
      t.name, t.project,
      trim(regexp_substr(t.error, '[^,]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as error
    from 
      temp t,
      table(cast(multiset(select level 
                          from dual connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(t.error, '[^,]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
)
SELECT Name, listagg(Error, ',') within group(order by 1) as result 
FROM split
GROUP BY Name
```

**OUTPUT**

As you can see you get a NULL because that extra comma `,`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several options in [Oracle forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2499711) as:

> ```
> with data as
>  (
>  select 
>
> '5,5,5,5,6,6,5,5,5,6,7,4,1,2,1,4,7,2' col from dual
> )
>  select listagg(col, ',') within group(order by 1) col
>  from (
>     select distinct regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, level) col
>     from data
>     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',')
>    )
> ```

Just replace the numbers with input as `'apple, apple, orange'`

Comment: can you check your query on rextester https://rextester.com/AFOPN7775  doesnt give me the expected output

Answer (score 1):

Using `trim` and `distinct` with `regexp` functions is very important to get the desired result as

```
select listagg(str,',') within group (order by 0) as Result
from
(
 select distinct trim(regexp_substr('apple, apple, orange','[^,]+', 1, level)) as str
   from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count('apple, apple, orange',',') + 1
);
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/AUW7471)