# How can I eliminate duplicate data in multiple columns query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I just asked the question about how I eliminate duplicate data in a column

[How can I eliminate duplicate data in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53377436/how-can-i-eliminate-duplicate-data-in-column)

this code below can delete duplicates in a column

```
with data as
(
  select 'apple, apple, apple, apple' col from dual
)
select listagg(col, ',') within group(order by 1) col
  from (
        select distinct regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, level) col
          from data
        connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',')
       )
```

next question is
now I do not know how to eliminate data in multiple columns

```
select 'apple, apple, apple' as col1, 
       'prince,prince,princess' as col2, 
       'dog, cat, cat' as col3
  from dual;
```

I would like to show

```
COL1     COL2                COL3
-----    ----------------    --------
apple    prince, princess    dog, cat
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this exercise and more importantly why in the world do you store all these delimited strings in single columns? It is a bad design practice and should be avoided at all cost. You will get a solution from someone here no doubt, but it is not worth putting such a dreadful structure  in  production code. The better approach should be to revamp the table structure / schema by following the rules of normalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use such a combination :

```
select  
    (
    select listagg(str,',') within group (order by 0)
      from
     (
      select distinct trim(regexp_substr('apple, apple, apple','[^,]+', 1, level)) as str
        from dual
     connect by level <= regexp_count('apple, apple, apple',',') + 1
     )
    ) as str1,
    (
    select listagg(str,',') within group (order by 0)
      from
     (
      select distinct trim(regexp_substr('prince,prince,princess','[^,]+', 1, level)) as str
        from dual
     connect by level <= regexp_count('prince,prince,princess',',') + 1
     )
    ) as str2,   
    (
    select listagg(str,',') within group (order by 0)
      from
     (
      select distinct trim(regexp_substr('dog, cat, cat','[^,]+', 1, level)) as str
        from dual
     connect by level <= regexp_count('dog, cat, cat',',') + 1
     )
    ) as str3    
 from dual;

 STR1         STR2           STR3
 ------  ---------------   --------
 apple   prince,princess   cat,dog
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/UFFF9036)